# How to select LAST record in group by using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to select the LAST of the record in group by in sql.
In my case I use this code

```
SELECT c_id
     , Max(transaction_num)
     , Max(trans_date) trans_date
     , doc_type
     , amount as balance
  from tbl_ledger 
 where doc_type = 'B' 
 group 
    by c_id
```

and the data of the selected column is this
[image]

so I basically trying to get the last balance amount. how can i select the last amount in sql?

the whole table content here : tbl_ledger
[image]

my output is getting the first balance amount:
[image]

Comment: just order your query by date : order by datechamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query gives you the record that has the latest `trans_date` for each `c_id`:

```
select t.*
from tbl_ledger t
where 
    doc_type = 'B'
    and trans_date = (
        select max(t1.trans_date)
        from tbl_ledger t1
        where t1.doc_type = 'B' and t1.c_id = t.c_id
    )
```